# Tax implications of using FSA funds during grace period

Tags: united-states, taxes, child-care

I have a dependent care FSA through work.  In 2014, I did not use all of the funds, but I have until March 15, 2015 to do so.  I will also have an FSA for 2015.

While I do my taxes through FreeFillableForms, I sometimes run my info through turbotax to double check my numbers.  One of the questions it asks for the child care deduction costs reads:

> **Carryover from 2013 Used in 2014?**
>
> Enter the amount of any excess
> contribution that you carried over from 2013 that you used to pay
> qualified expenses during the grace period in 2014.

My questions are:

- How does this impact the actual filling out of forms?
- Does this change anything for tax year 2014, or will it only make a difference in 2015?
- (For curiosity and completeness) Is there any difference in the tax impact of this scenario if this were a healthcare FSA instead?  (Seems like they would be treated the same.)

Other details:

- My carryover is relatively small, only $50.
- My total FSA amount was about $4500 ... more than the $3000 allowance for the dependent care deduction I could take for 1 eligible child.
- I actually have far more spending on dependent care than I had in my FSA, but due to only having the FSA for 3 months (changed jobs in September) and having a claim misinterpreted and being reimbursed for less than it should have been, I didn't get through all of my money.  It was easier to spend the $50 in 2015 instead of spending hours on the phone getting them to fix the reimbursement.
- I live in the US.